# Get nested JSON keys only

Tags: jquery, json

Example JSON

```
{
  "one": [{
    "A": {"name":"example"},
    "B": {}
  }],
  "two": [{
    "A": {"name":"booger"},
    "B": {}
  }]
}
```

Using this I can get keys "one" and "two" to be listed.

```
$.getJSON('blahblah.js', function(data){
  $.each(data, function(key){
    console.log(key);
  });
});
```

But using this, I can't get "A" and "B" to be listed.

```
$.getJSON('blahblah.js', function(data){
  $.each(data.one, function(key){
    console.log(key);
  });
});
```

Why not? And how do I get those inner keys(is this the correct term?) to be listed.
Thanks

Comment: `$.each(data.one[0])`

Comment: based on your data "one" and "two" each contain a single dimension array.  So you are either not going deep enough to obtain the other objects or maybe you didn't mean to use those square brackets.

Comment: @Aioros solution works, Thanks.

Comment: @Fnostro, it does need to be an array right? if I lose the square brackets, and drop [0] from the date.one, it doesn't work..

Comment: see snippet in my anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...not sure what you're seeing then...

```js
var jsontext_withbrackets =
  '{"one":[{"A":{"name": "example"},"B":{}}],\
  "two":[{"A":{"name": "booger" },"B":{}}]}';

var obj1 = JSON.parse(jsontext_withbrackets);

var jsontext_withoutbrackets =
  '{"one":{"A":{"name": "example"},"B":{}},\
  "two":{"A":{"name": "booger" },"B":{}} }';

var obj2 = JSON.parse(jsontext_withoutbrackets);

console.log(obj1.one[0]);
console.log(obj2.one);
```

Comment: You were correct. I must have done something wrong. My name is clueless for a reason. I will accept your answer, thank you for expanding.

Comment: Glad to help.  We were all clueless once :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$.each(data, function (key) {
  data[key].forEach((element) => {
    $.each(element, function (item) {
      console.log(key + ":"+item + ":" + JSON.stringify(element[item]));
    });
  });
});
```

result

```
one:A:{"name":"example"}
one:B:{}
two:A:{"name":"booger"}
two:B:{}
```

Comment: Thank you. The other answer was more direct to what I was wondering about. Though this is more verbose, and I may use it.